# Cannot get Eigen to multithread

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, eigen

I am developing a c++ program using the Eigen library. It involves lots of matrix multiplications.

I know Eigen supports parallelisation for matrix multiplications but I cannot seem to get the thread count to exceed 1.

I have put the following in my code:

```
    Eigen::initParallel();
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    Eigen::setNbThreads(4);
```

I am compiling with the OpenMp library:

```
-fopenmp
```

I am running my code with:

```
  OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./program
```

I am verifying that only 1 thread is running by:

1. calling Eigen::nbThreads()
2. running htop and observing the thread count for the process.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have searched online and I think I have tried all of the common fixes.

EDIT:

Example of code which reproduces problem:

```
void m_multiply() {

Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> m1;
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> m2;
m1.resize(1000,1000);
m2.resize(1000,1000);
m1.setRandom();
m2.setRandom();

while (true) {
    m1 *= m2;
    std::cout << Eigen::nbThreads << std::endl;
}

}
```

Comment: What code do you call that shall be parallelized? What's the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also, except for compiling with `-fopenmp`, none of the extra steps are necessary. OpenMP detects the thread count automatically. Eigen calls `initParallel()` automatically.

Comment: @Homer512 - please see a code sample above. This prints 1 repeatedly.

Comment: @tom1989 you need to have one section of code in your question that can be copy/pasted and compiled directly that has the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem.  However, I don't see anything in your edit code that I would expect to see parallelized.   How many threads can it use to do one matrix multiply at a time?

Comment: @xaxxon How many threads? Potentially one million when multiplying 1000x1000 matrices. [Eigen is internally parallelized](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html) and dense matrix multiplication is the poster-child for parallelized algorithms.

Comment: @tom1989 `Eigen::nbThreads` is a function. Change the line to `std::cout << Eigen::nbThreads() << std::endl;`. If I do that, I get 16 threads (as expected) and all cores are utilized for the duration of the program. What's your platform? What does `nproc` report on the command line?

Comment: @Homer512 Many thanks - I realised my error and it now clearly shows that Eigen is using 4 threads in that test code. What I am now trying to work out is why my actual code, which is somewhat different to the above code but still uses matrix multiplication, is not using 4 threads. The matrices are of the same size.

Is there anything I should look out for which might stop Eigen from using multiple threads (e.g. in the same expression combining multiplication with the "+" operator)?

Comment: @tom1989 additions and multiplications by scalars should be folded into the operation automatically. Some types of multiplications aren't parallelized, e.g. small fixed-size matrices or triangular and `selfadjointView`. Other than that, you need to show the actual expression

Comment: Another possibility is that the code is already in a `pragma omp parallel` section or something similar. Since OpenMP by default does not nest parallel sections, an ineffective parallel section surrounding the code can disable the internal parallelization